# Подстановка ссылки по клику на радио

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть батоны

```
    <div class="product-choice-wrapper">
<label><input type="radio" name="pc" value="" checked="checked"> Oregon antik</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pc" value=""> Oregon royal</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pc" value=""> Oregon perlamutr</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pc" value=""> Нат. кожа Madras + к/з</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="pc" value=""> Нат. кожа Consul + к/з</label>
    </div>
```

Есть ссылка со значением по умолчанию

```
<a href="">Нужно выбрать прежде чем нажать</a>
```

Нужно в зависимости от батона заменять ссылки полность со всеми параметрами.

Примерно такого вида

```
<a rel="nofollow" class="bt3 addtoCart" onclick="arSKU[1]['CART']= 'inCart'; return addToCart(this, 'detail', 'Уже в корзине', 'cart'); " id="catalog_add2cart_link_297"><span></span>Купить</a>

<a href="/?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=298" rel="nofollow" class="bt3 addtoCart" onclick="arSKU[0]['CART']= 'inCart'; return addToCart(this, 'detail', 'Уже в корзине', 'cart'); " id="catalog_add2cart_link_298"><span></span>Купить</a>
```

Как это реализовать на jquery?

Comment: - за баттон

Comment: @eicto ну он хотя бы транслитом не балуется, как многие. За это вообще надо руки отрывать по самую задницу, из которой они растут

Comment: `<input type="radio" />` вообще не button :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не надо обзывать переключатели батонами, а то они вас найдут и...

..пишите код, как будто его будет проверять мужик с большой дубиной!

http://jsfiddle.net/vdann/e2LS9/3/embedded/